# MySQL error code 1054: Unknow columns in "field list"

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I'm currently using MySQL 8.0.27 on Windows 10.
I'm using EpxressJS, Sequelize to make an API. These commands worked fine:

```
sequelize-cli db:create
sequelize-cli db:migrate
sequelize-cli db:seed:all
```

Then I go to MySQL workbench and test this insert query which was successfully executed.

```
insert into authaccounts (email, password, privilege, companyid) 
values ("cd@gmail.com", "1", "admin", 1);
```

Then I use Postman to create an account (through API), maybe it changed MySQL schema or something I did'nt find out.

AuthAccount model (sequelize)

```
AuthAccount.init(
    {
      email: DataTypes.STRING,
      password: DataTypes.STRING,
      privilege: DataTypes.STRING,
      companyID: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: "AuthAccount",
    }
  );
```

Postman result

[image: Postman result]

MySQL workbench result

[image: MySQL workbench]

Comment: Can you describe table

Comment: You can see the table columnns in the second image, on the left of the picture.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry. It's caused by a SQL trigger. My bad!

```
create trigger mergeAccountToEmp 
      after insert on authAccounts for each row 
      insert into employees 
      set email=NEW.email,
      id=NEW.id,
      companyID=NEW.companyID;
```

The table employees doesn't have column "companyID" so the trigger fire failed.

Comment: Thanks! I will remember it.